# Do deaf people sleep better?

Tags: sleep

Since deaf people can't hear, is relaxing and falling asleep easier for them? In general, do they sleep better than hearing people?

Of course some hearing people have no trouble getting to sleep, but others awaken whenever they hear a sound.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not biology

Comment: @rg255 - since when are sleep and sensation not Biology?

Comment: ok perhaps better to say I think it is trivial, does not deal with any kind of biological question or problem, and is unlikely to be of interest to the target audience (students, academics and active researchers)

Comment: You must also consider the reason for the condition. Are they deaf because of something mechanical in the ear? Something neurological? Maybe even psychosomatic? I would postulate that the total lack of one sense from birth would have no discernable effect on sleep patterns. As well, I would think that induced heading loss would harm sleep, because of the likely depression to go with loss of hearing.

Answer (score 2):

Let's firstly differentiate deafness - profoundly impaired ability to hear, and other states where the subjects can still hear at different degrees.

Secondly, differentiate the congenital deafness & infantile hearing loss and hearing loss in adults who previously had normal hearing.

The subjects with congenital and very early infantile hearing loss would have better sleep characteristics (this state will affect psychological state in a lesser degree than one acquired in more mature & "conscious" state), while persons who have lost their normal hearing [would have](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4158149/) abnormal sleep patterns at least in the period when they have just realized that they are going to lose their hearing. After this "preliminary" period, the sleep pattern should be dependent on the person's psychological status and other similar factors.

Many persons will mention that while using ear plugs they feel that their sleep is better comparing with "un-plugged" sleep.

sources

1. [Characteristics of sleep in deafness](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9658468). Rev Neurol. 1998 Jun;26(154).
2. Non-scientific [source](http://limpingchicken.com/2014/05/08/the-question-do-deaf-people-sleep-better-at-night-than-hearing-people/).

Please pay attention that scientific sources are scarce, thus take the answer as one of limited evidence.